# R nested for loop in Python?

Tags: python, r, loops, for-loop

***I know R better than Python. I've written this in R. How do I do this in Python?***

This is a nested for loop in R. It takes each record, column binds it to all other records, and builds a Data Frame from row binding on itself.

Here is what I'm trying to do. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNY27.jpg)

create data

```
X = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
Y = c("abc", "def", "ghi")
b = data.frame(X, Y)
```

get unique values for each column 'X'

```
u <- unique(b$X)
```

create empty data frames

```
d = data.frame()
g = data.frame()
```

nested for loop

```
# for each unique value in 'X'
for(i in u){
    # subset data frame b
    s <- subset(b, X == i)  
        # for each unique value in 'X'
        for(k in u){
            # subset data frame b
            j <- subset(b, X == k)
            # create column of values from s, and values from j
            f <- cbind(s,j) 
            # loop through each value of 'X'
            g <- rbind(g,f)
        } 
   # loop through each value of 'X' again
   p <- rbind(d, g) 
 }

# print results
p
```

Comment: even in R it's pretty poorly written...

Comment: That's not how you **would** do it in R: `p1 <- data.frame(X1 = rep(X, each = length(X)),
         Y1 = rep(Y, each = length(X)),
         X2 = rep(X, times = length(X)),
         Y2 = rep(Y, times = length(X)))`

Comment: Please write what you expect so that it can be understood by a R illiterate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added an image which helps explain it.

Comment: or `cbind(expand.grid(X, X), expand.grid(sort(c(Y, Y)), sort(c(Y, Y))))` and reorder the columns if you care. by the way your picture doesn't match your example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of Symbolix's much improved one-liner, I would propose to use list comprehension in Python (version 2.7) to construct `p` as a list of tuples (since Python doesn't have data frames):

```
X = range(6)
Y = ["abc","def","ghi"]
p = [(X[-1 + (index + 6) / 6], Y[-3 + (index) / 6], X[index % 6], Y[index % 3]) for index in range(36)]
```

In short, `p` is defined using list comprehension (which you can read up on [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) with some tricks (negative indexing and modular arithmetic) to make its definition compact.

```
>>> for thing in p:
...   print thing
... 
(0, 'abc', 0, 'abc')
(0, 'abc', 1, 'def')
(0, 'abc', 2, 'ghi')
(0, 'abc', 3, 'abc')
(0, 'abc', 4, 'def')
(0, 'abc', 5, 'ghi')
(1, 'def', 0, 'abc')
(1, 'def', 1, 'def')
(1, 'def', 2, 'ghi')
(1, 'def', 3, 'abc')
(1, 'def', 4, 'def')
(1, 'def', 5, 'ghi')
(2, 'ghi', 0, 'abc')
(2, 'ghi', 1, 'def')
(2, 'ghi', 2, 'ghi')
(2, 'ghi', 3, 'abc')
(2, 'ghi', 4, 'def')
(2, 'ghi', 5, 'ghi')
(3, 'abc', 0, 'abc')
(3, 'abc', 1, 'def')
(3, 'abc', 2, 'ghi')
(3, 'abc', 3, 'abc')
(3, 'abc', 4, 'def')
(3, 'abc', 5, 'ghi')
(4, 'def', 0, 'abc')
(4, 'def', 1, 'def')
(4, 'def', 2, 'ghi')
(4, 'def', 3, 'abc')
(4, 'def', 4, 'def')
(4, 'def', 5, 'ghi')
(5, 'ghi', 0, 'abc')
(5, 'ghi', 1, 'def')
(5, 'ghi', 2, 'ghi')
(5, 'ghi', 3, 'abc')
(5, 'ghi', 4, 'def')
(5, 'ghi', 5, 'ghi')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.